# checkbox not working in data table when paginated

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a data table using jquery that display a list of data. I implemented a checkbox on the first column that I can check for each record or check all the records at once. If there is one checkbox or more selected then the approve and reject button would show up. While all these can work at the moment but if I select a next page and start checking any checkbox, the approve/reject button will not display.

Code:

```
<article class="col-xs-6 text-right">
            <button id="approveButton" class="btn btn-success update-button" value="1">Approve</button>
            <button id="rejectButton" class="btn btn-danger update-button" value="2">Reject</button>
        </article>

var $table = $("#dt_basic").DataTable({
    "scrollY": ($(window).height() - 270)+"px",
    "scrollX": false,
    "pageLength": ' . Yii::$app->params['settings']['listing_length'] . ',
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "columnDefs": [{ "targets": [0, 6], "searchable": false, "orderable": false, "visible": true, className: "text-center-desktop" }],
    "deferLoading": ' . $total . ',
    "order": [],
    "ajax": "' . Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['xxxx']) . '",
    "sDom": "<\'dt-toolbar\'<\'col-xs-12 col-sm-9\'f><\'col-sm-3 hidden-xs\'l>>r"+
        "t"+
        "<\'dt-toolbar-footer\'<\'col-sm-5 col-xs-12 hidden-xs\'i><\'col-xs-12 col-sm-7\'p>>",
    "autoWidth" : true,
    "preDrawCallback" : function() {
        responsiveHelper_dt_basic = new ResponsiveDatatablesHelper($(\'#dt_basic\'), {tablet : 1024, phone : 480});
    },
    "rowCallback" : function(nRow) {
        responsiveHelper_dt_basic.createExpandIcon(nRow);
    },
    "drawCallback" : function(oSettings) {
        responsiveHelper_dt_basic.respond();
        var pagination = $(this).closest(".dataTables_wrapper").find(".dataTables_paginate");
        pagination.toggle(this.api().page.info().pages > 1);
    }
});

    $("#approveButton").hide();
    $("#rejectButton").hide();

    $("#masterCheck").on("click", function (e) { 
        if ($(this).is(":checked", true)) {
            $(".subChk").prop("checked",true);
        } else {
            $(".subChk").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });

    //This would not detect if checkbox is ticked in next page
    $("input:checkbox").on("change",function(){  
        if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length > 0) {
            $("#approveButton").show();
            $("#rejectButton").show();
        } else {
            $("#approveButton").hide();
            $("#rejectButton").hide();
        }
    }); 

    $(".update-button").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var status =  $(this).val(); 
        let allVals = [];
        $(".subChk:checked").each(function() {
            allVals.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });

        console.log(allVals);
        let join_selected_values = allVals.join(",");
        $.ajax({
            url: "updatewithdrawbulk",
            type: "UPDATE",
            data: {
                ids: join_selected_values,
                type: status
            },
            success: function(data) {
                location.reload();
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("There is some error, please try again");
            }
        });
    });
```

After going to next page, checking the master checkbox will work (checked all sub checkbox as well) and approve/reject button will show. My only issue is when I tick any checkbox individually, it will not show the buttons.

I was wondering if this is an issue with the code or jquery data table?

Comment: The core issue will be that - when you are attaching the change event to the checkboxes at the start - it will do that for all that currently exist - when a new set is loaded - these checkboxes have not had the same event attached. You may want to hook into the event - drawCallback? - thats called after these new rows appear to again bind the event to the new checkboxes

Comment: I just added the on change event in my drawCallback and it works. Can you post the answer so I can mark as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when you are attaching these .on bindings - it will only attach for the elements that currently exist in the html to be found.

When your next set of rows are drawn - these do not have the events bound to them.

If you hook into the event callback that tells you when new rows have appeared - you should bind your events again so that these new rows work as expected.

In the sample I would expect this to be achieved within the drawCallback event.